# Overleaf list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents

The list of tables in my report isn't showing when I am using \listoftables. Here's a list of all of my tables.

```
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}

\chapter{Data Statistical Summaries}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2.3cm}||p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Phase One Data} \\
\hline
Data set&  Image No &Min &1st Qu &Median &Mean &3rd Qu &Max \\
\hline
Young                      &68  &2.0 &308.2 &442.5 &430.4 &567.5& 880.0\\
Young curated              &57 &34.0 &375.5 &467.0 &478.6 &589.5 &880.0\\
Senescent                 &53 &14.00 &25.00 &59.50 &60.46 &85.25 &171.00\\
Senescent curated           &66 &10.00 &25.75 &59.50  &60.46 &85.25 &171.00 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Phase one data statistical summary}
\label{tab:statistical_summary01}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2.3cm}||p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Phase one Data with transformations} \\
\hline
Data set&  Image No &Min &1st Qu &Median &Mean &3rd Qu &Max \\
\hline
Young                      &64  &14.0  &320.5 &442.5 &437.3 &567.5 &880.0\\
Young curated              &112 &34.0 &375.0 &467.0 &472.4 &582.2 &880.0\\
Senescent                 &130 &10.00 &25.75 &25.75 &60.34 &85.25 &171.00\\
Senescent curated           & & & & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Phase one data statistical summary with the transformations}
\label{tab:statistical_summary02}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2.3cm}||p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Phase two data} \\
\hline
Data set&  Image No &Min &1st Qu &Median &Mean &3rd Qu &Max \\
\hline
Young/Senescent              &1045&1.0&225.0&286.0&350.9&459.0&1196.0\\
Young               &1045&1.0&42.00&61.00&68.64&95.00&180.00\\
Senescent           &1045&0&156.0&217.0&282.3&396.0&1112.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Phase two data statistical summary}
\label{tab:statistical_summary03}
\end{table}

\newpage

% Experiments Tables
\chapter{Experiment Tables}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1.5cm}||p{0.7cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{2.2cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Training experiments on phase one images} \\
\hline
Model& Batch Size &Cell Type &Epoch &Learning Rate &Image No & Completion time \\
\hline
Base CNN &16  &Young           &50   &0.0001 &72  &00:25:54\\
VGG16    &16  &Young           &50   &0.0001 &72  &00:33:19\\
Base CNN &16 &Young curated   &50   &0.0001 &56 &00:42:10\\
VGG16    &16 &Young curated   &50   &0.0001 &56 &00:51:30\\
Base CNN &16 &Senescent         &50   &0.0001 &72  &00:26:25\\
VGG16    &16 &Senescent         &50   &0.0001 &72  &00:33:54\\
Base CNN &16 &Senescent curated &50   &0.0001 &65  &00:22:38\\
VGG16    &16 &Senescent curated &50   &0.0001 &65  &00:30:52\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Experiments on phase one images using CNN and VGG16 models}
\label{tab:Deep_Learning_Experiments}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1.5cm}||p{0.7cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{2.2cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Training experiments on phase one transformed images} \\
\hline
Model& Batch Size &Cell Type &Epoch &Learning Rate &Image No & Completion time \\
\hline
Base CNN &16  &Young           &50   &0.0001 &143 &00:48:57\\
VGG16    &16  &Young           &50   &0.0001 &143 &01:21:19\\
Base CNN &16 &Young curated   &50   &0.0001 &111 &00:41:16\\
VGG16    &16 &Young curated   &50   &0.0001 &111 &01:06:39\\
Base CNN &16 &Senescent         &50   &0.0001 &143 &00:48:58\\
VGG16    &16 &Senescent         &50   &0.0001 &143 &01:11:40\\
Base CNN &16 &Senescent curated &50   &0.0001 &129 &00:52:02\\
VGG16    &16 &Senescent curated &50   &0.0001 &129 &01:07:04\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Experiments on phase one transformed images using CNN and VGG16 models}
\label{tab:Deep_Learning_Experiments_with_Transformations}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1.5cm}||p{0.7cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{2.2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Training experiments on phase two of images} \\
\hline
Model& Batch Size &Cell Type &Epoch &Learning Rate &Image No & Completion time\\
\hline
Base CNN &16 &Young           &100   &0.0001 &1045  &04:12:10\\
VGG16    &16 &Young           &100   &0.0001 &1045  &05:16:33\\
Base CNN &16 &Senescent         &100   &0.0001 &1045  &03:37:05\\
VGG16    &16 &Senescent         &100   &0.0001 &1045  &04:49:32\\
Base CNN &16 &Young,Senescent &100   &0.0001 &1045  &\\
VGG16    &16 &Young,Senescent &100   &0.0001 &1045  &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Experiments on phase two of microscopy images}
\label{tab:Deep_Learning_Experiments_new_microscopy}
\end{table}

\newpage

\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1.5cm}||p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.3cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Experiments 1-4 Results}\\
\hline
Model &Cell Type& Train Count Error &Train Loss &Test Count Error &Test Loss\\
\hline
Base CNN &Young         &190.60 &62139.98 &145.07 &54093.07 \\
VGG16    &Young                &89.15 &16918.91 &133.58 &16918.91  \\
Base CNN &Young curated        &176.83 &58145.10 &171.48 &46047.87 \\
VGG16    &Young curated        &104.81 &19031.24 &97.02 &13485.88 \\
Base CNN &Senescent            &32.55 &1552.48 &18.20 &623.78 \\
VGG16    &Senescent            &13.27 &580.55 &18.47 &623.14 \\
Base CNN &Senescent curated    &31.83 &1539.21 &26.00 &1073.62 \\
VGG16    &Senescent curated   &14.11 &589.81 &15.88 &517.51 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Outcomes Experiments 1-4}
\label{tab:training_outcomes_1-4}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1.5cm}||p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.3cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Experiments 1A-4A Results}\\
\hline
Model &Cell Type& Train Count Error &Train Loss &Test Count Error &Test Loss\\
\hline
Base CNN &Young                &168.61 &51006.46 &137.60 &31649.65 \\
VGG16    &Young                &59.46 &9082.75 &65.95 &7344.12  \\
Base CNN &Young curated        &147.90 &42374.04 &143.20 &39325.26 \\
VGG16    &Young curated        &71.48 &11057.34 &85.11 &11479.96 \\
Base CNN &Senescent            &29.19 &1290.15 &31.53 &1286.28 \\
VGG16    &Senescent            &9.44 &310.50 &11.34 &263.47 \\
Base CNN &Senescent curated    &29.44 &1323.50 &29.53 &1215.88 \\
VGG16    &Senescent curated    &11.11 &400.71 &10.80 &327.68 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Outcomes Experiments 1A-4A}
\label{tab:training_outcomes1A-4A}
\end{table}

\newpage

% Experiments with Data Transformations:
\chapter{Experiments with Data Transformations}
\section{Experiment 1A}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{TesnorBoard_Graphs/Exp01A_Tensorboard.png}
\caption{Experiment 1A -  Graphs A \& C show the test and train count error, B \& D show the test and train loss for CNN and VGG16 models using transformed images containing young cells}
\label{fig:exp01A}
\end{figure}

\section{Experiment 2A}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{TesnorBoard_Graphs/Exp02A_Tensorboard.png}
\caption{Experiment 2A -  Graphs A \& B show the test and train count error, B \& D show the test and train loss for CNN and VGG16 models using transformed curated images containing young cells}
\label{fig:exp02A}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\section{Experiment 3A}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{TesnorBoard_Graphs/Exp03A_Tensorboard.png}
\caption{Experiment 3A -  Graphs A \& C show the test and train count error, B \& D show the test and train loss for CNN and VGG16 models using images containing Senescent cells}
\label{fig:exp03A}
\end{figure}


\section{Experiment 4A}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{TesnorBoard_Graphs/Exp04A_Tensorboard.png}
\caption{Experiment 4A -  Graphs A \& C show the test and train count error, B \& D show the test and train loss for CNN and VGG16 models using transformed curated images containing Senescent cells}
\label{fig:exp04A}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\chapter{Linear Regression Graphs}

\section{Linear regression for raw counts}
\vfill
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{images/raw_counts.png}
\caption{Linear regression graph for raw count provided by Edward Fielder}
\label{fig:row_counts}
\end{figure}
\vfill

\newpage

\section{Manual vs Old ICY Protocol}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{images/ManualvsOldICY.png}
\caption{The Manual vs Old ICY count provided by Edward Fielder}
\label{fig:ManualvsOldICY}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{Manual vs ICY count}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{images/ManualvsICY.png}
\caption{The Manual vs ICY count provided by Edward Fielder }
\label{fig:ManualvsICY}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{Manual vs VGG16 count}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{images/Manual_VGG16.png}
\caption{The Manual vs VGG16 count provided by Edward Fielder}
\label{fig:Manual_VGG16}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\end{appendices}
```

The preamble file contains this code:

```
%\documentclass{article} % For LaTeX2e
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{iclr2020_conference,times}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
% Optional math commands from https://github.com/goodfeli/dlbook_notation.
\input{math_commands.tex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[page,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citation.bib} %Imports bibliography file
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ %\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}
\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
\usepackage[font=small,font=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{images/university_logo.png}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\vspace{0.8cm}
\Huge

\vspace{0.8cm}   
%\vfill

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newcommand{\fix}{\marginpar{FIX}}
\newcommand{\new}{\marginpar{NEW}}

\newpage

\tableofcontents


\newpage

\input{chapter01_introduction}
\input{chapter02_models}
\input{chapter03_results}
\input{chapter04_discussion}
\input{chapter05_conclusions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography
\newpage
\input{appendices}
\section*{Acronyms}
\input{acro_list}
\newpage
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, i do please scroll down the code i provided.

Comment: Yes sorry. These are separate files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If i remove \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}} from my appendix page the list of tables start to show up, but i need this code to stop appendix sections  appearing in the content page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: well that did look suspicious but the standard listoftables .. oh yes that;s it, sorry I was thinking it didn't affect listoftables by default but it does (any value less than 1 stops it in artilce class) just set it back to 1 inside the appendix

Comment: If i set it to 1 the list of tables appears. But, i don't want to show any of the appendix sections in the content page, which what happens if i set it to one, if i set it to -1 this doesn't show any of the appendix section.

Comment: just set it to 1 in each table, before the caption, if you must...

Comment: Thanks! I have added 1 after the first table this is caused the all sections to show on the content page. Can I stop the section in the appendix page appearing in the content page